# Почему при перезапуске phpStorm (Windows) слетает composer?

Tags: phpstorm, composer

При перезапуске **phpStorm** и открытии проекта перестает работать **composer**. Приходится каждый раз заново открывать **Tools/Composer/Init composer** и указывать путь к **php.exe** и **composer.path**. Данная проблема наблюдается при открытии лишь некоторых проектов.
Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

**phpStorm 10.0.3**

Comment: вам в техподдержку

Comment: кстати говоря, техподдержка у JetBrains на высоте. На любой коммент в твитторе отвечают оперативно и баг-трекер у них норм работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтоб работали настройки композера нужно выполнить следующие 2 простых условия.

1. Нужно чтоб был настроен интерпретатор PHP: `Languages & Frameworks/PHP` Interpreter (выбрать исполняемый файл PHP php.exe) чуть выше PHP language level должен соответствовать версии выбранного интерпретатора.
2. Собственно, настроить сам композер. Для этого:

   - он должен быть доступен в проекте: либо установлен глобально, либо в папке проекта должен находиться файл composer.phar. Для глобальной настройки убедитесь, что команда `composer` в консоли выдает список команд.
   - указать путь к используемому файлу composer.phar либо глобально доступному, либо локально установленном в проекте.

Возможные проблемы:

1. Файл композера недоступен для вашего проекта. Убедитесь, что в папке вашего проекта доступна команда `composer` для глобальной настройки или `php composer.phar` для локальной.
2. В настройках PhpStorm указан НЕ тот файл composer.phar, который доступен в вашем проекте.
3. PhpStorm хранит локальные настройки проекта в папке `.idea`. Убедитесь, что вы не перезаписываете, не удаляете и не изменяете эту папку для вашего проекта при перезагрузке. Убедитесь так же, что путь к проекту указан правильно и не был изменен при перезагрузке.

В конце хочется сказать, что вы очень ограничиваете ответы на ваш вопрос изначально сузив их до той части, которая уже не принесла вам положительного результата. Лучше бы вы спросили, как реализовать именно то, что вам нужно. Например, как установить новый пакет в проект при помощи композера? Возможно, и скорее всего, есть более простые пути решения вашей проблемы, о которых вы просто не знаете.

Answer (score 0):

Это "особенность" настройки composer через "**Tools/Composer/Init composer**". Настройте *composer* в проекте вручную.

1. Откройте настройки "**File/Settings**"
2. Перейдите в раздел "**Languages &
   Frameworks/PHP**"
3. Выберите интерпретатор *php*
4. Перейдите в раздел "**Languages &
   Frameworks/PHP/Composer**"
5. Укажите путь до *composer.phar* и *comopser.json*

Comment: Сделано. Результат тот же, к сожалению.

Comment: Проверьте сохраняются ли настройки composer в файле "<project>/.idea/workspace.xml" `<component name="ComposerSettings">
    <pharConfigPath>path/to/composer.json</pharConfigPath>
    <pharPath>path/to/composer.phar</pharPath>
  </component>` @LANSELOT